# Flash message with remote actions with Rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a silly question. 
I'm stuck on that and i don't know how to solve it :)

I have some basic actions like create and destroy comments. I have added the remote => true attribute.

My actions are rendered with a create.js.haml and a destroy.js.haml.

```
$(".comments").prepend("#{escape_javascript(render(@comment))}");
$("#comments_box .form #new_comment").get(0).reset();
```

In my controller i have a

```
flash[:notice] = 'Comment created'
```

And I would like to update the flash message into the layout....
Into my layout i have this :

```
 - flash.each do |name, msg|
        = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
```

What would be the nicer way to create or update the flash message from jQuery (View) ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem like that :

In my Layout i added :

```
#flash_messages
  = render :partial => 'layouts/flash', :locals => { :flash => flash }
```

The flash partial contains :

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
- if defined?(flush_flash) and flush_flash == true
  - flash.clear
```

And in my js.haml

```
$("#flash_messages").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'layouts/flash', :locals => {:flash => flash, :flush_flash => true}))}");
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: You should not call a partal flash, you can have name clashes. If you want to avoid headeaches, rename the partial to something like `_flash_messages.html.erb`